# Ruby 1.9, MySQL character encoding issue

Tags: mysql, ruby, encoding, ruby-1.9

Our Rails 3 app needs to be able to accept foreign characters like ä and こ, and save them to our MySQL db, which has its character_set as 'utf8.'

One of our models runs a validation which is used to strip out all the non-word characters in its name, before being saved.  In Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2, the following was sufficient:

```
def strip_non_words(string)
  string.gsub!(/\W/,'')
end
```

This stripped out bad characters, but preserved things like 'ä', 'こ', and '3.'  With Ruby 1.9's new encodings, however, that statement no longer works - it is now removing those characters as well as the others we don't want.  I am trying to find a way to do that.

Changing the gsub to something like this:

```
def strip_non_words(string)
  string.gsub!(/[[:punct]]/,'')
end
```

lets the string pass through fine, but then the database kicks up the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation
```

Running the string through Iconv to try and convert it, like so:

```
def strip_non_words(string)
  Iconv.conv('LATIN1', 'UTF8', string)
  string.gsub!(/[[:punct]]/,'')
end
```

Results in *this* error:

```
Iconv::IllegalSequence: "こäè" # "こäè" being a test string
```

I'm basically at my whits end here.  Does anyone know of a way to do do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a bit of an interesting fix.

I discovered that Ruby has a regex I could use, but only for ASCII strings.  So I had to convert the string to ASCII, run the regex, then convert it back for submission to the db.  End result looks like this:

```
def strip_non_words(string)
  string_encoded = string.force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
  string_encoded.gsub!(/\p{Word}+/, '') # non-word characters
  string_reencoded = string_encoded.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')
  string_reencoded #return
end
```

Turns out you have to encode things separately due to how Ruby handles changing a character encoding: http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/03/08/rails-3-patch-encoding-bug-while-action-caching-with-memcachestore/